# Using og:image set to a php script doesn't show up in facebook feed

Tags: php, image, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have been working on a website for a friend and trying to integrate it with facebook. He is a semi-professional photographer and does photo shoots for weddings and such. As part of this, I had to integrate a bit of a security system which uses a script to get images instead of directly accessing them through a link. The script takes a photograph id and the size requested (full size or thumbnail), checks the database to see if it is publicly accessible, and reads the image to the browser (using header() to change the mime type). However, when I use 'Like' buttons on the page with og:image set to this photo retrieving script, facebook doesn't display an image. I am guessing this has something to do with the 'safe_image.php' script that facebook uses to load images on pages. Does anyone know a way to work around this?

Here are my og tags for the page I am trying to make show up in the feed just in case I did something wrong:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Wedding Samples"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thevandykecollection.com/index.php?f=viewphoto&id=289&thumbnail"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thevandykecollection.com/index.php?f=portfolio&id=23"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Van Dyke Collection"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="510746110,500416148"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem quite a bit too, and was able to solve by making sure I had adhered to the [Facebook guidelines on the image size and dimensions:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

> og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the
>   graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum
>   aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may
>   include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your
>   page.

EDIT:

I tried to load your image, and it's basically going to a 404 page. I'm sure you know that, but if not, that's the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding an

```
<img src="...">
```

tag in the body fixes this problem sometime too.